# Diferença entre ExecuteQuery, SqlQuery e ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: c#

Qual a diferença entre ExecuteQuery, SqlQuery e ExecuteSqlCommand?

Quando saber qual devo usar?

Comment: ExecuteQuery e SqlQuery são usados para executar consultas padrões de SQL, um select e afins, ja o ExecuteSqlCommand é mais usado para executar ações de Update,Insert,Delete..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- *ExecuteSqlCommand*: Executa um comando, não serve para consultas, ou seja você utilizará para `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`.
- *ExecuteQuery*:  Executa uma consulta com parâmetro, recebendo primeiro a Query e depois os parâmetros como no exemplo a seguir:

  ```
  db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(@"SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle,Address, City,
  Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax FROM  dbo.Customers  WHERE  City = {0}", "London");
  ```
- *SqlQuery*: Executa uma consulta(sem a passagem de parâmetros de forma segura como em `ExecuteQuery`.

Note que `ExecuteQuery` é bem parecido com `SqlQuery` porém é recomendado por segurança utiliza-la sempre que for consultar utilizando parâmetros.